# Convert textarea to array and indented text to nested-arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, textarea

I am wanting to take text input from a Form Textarea POST in PHP and iterate over each line of text and create a PHP array with the text.

The catch is I want to take lines of text that are indented with 4 spaces before them and make those lines be a sub nested array under the above array item.

I am not sure how to do this at the moment so would appreciate any ideas on it.

```
// basic demo to show each line of textarea post
$text = $_POST['textarea'];
foreach(explode("\n", $text) as $line) {
    echo $line;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

---

UPDATE

An idea so far something along the lines of this as a start maybe....

```
$text = $_POST['textarea'];
$in_nested_array = false;
$array = array();
foreach(explode("\n", $text) as $line) {

    if($line is 4 spaces){
        $in_nested_array = true;
        $array[''][$line];
    }else{
        //if in nested array and new line is not nested, add to root array
        if($in_nested_array){

        }else{
            $in_nested_array = false;
            $array[] = $line;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but have you tried `\t` or number of spaces at the begining after exploding?

Comment: @SougataBose I don't have trouble detecting a line space I am wanting to nest them under parent arrays

Comment: Then if there is any space or tab then set the sub array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a first try:

```
$str = <<<EOD
bar
    baz
        meh
        lol
            tuuut
moo
EOD;

function parse($lines, $depth = 0, $cur = 0)
{
    $retVal = array();

    for ($i = $cur; $i < count($lines); $i++)
    {
        $line = $lines[$i];
        $lDepth = strlen($line) - strlen(ltrim($line, " "));

        if ($lDepth == $depth)
        {
            $retVal[] = array("line" => ltrim($line, " "));
        } elseif ($lDepth == $depth + 4) {
            $children = parse($lines, $depth + 4, $i);
            $retVal[count($retVal) - 1]["children"] = $children;
            $i += count($children);
        }
    }

    return $retVal;
}

$lines = explode("\n", $str);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(parse($lines));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [line] => bar
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [line] => baz
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [line] => meh
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [line] => lol
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [line] => tuuut
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [line] => moo
        )

)
```

Comment: Hey. First, I really want to thank you for this snippet. [I did some changes](https://gist.github.com/RedPhantom/f61adf58858f3e8099d48dd1813fcf3b) because I needed attributes important to include in the JSON this array would be converted to. For some reason, when I add another root element (depth = 0), the code "thinks" it's the root level of the previous element. Input included in the Gist. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To seperate by 4 spaces:

```
$txt = preg_split('/    +/', $text);
```

Comment: I don't have trouble detecting a line space I am wanting to nest them under parent arrays

Comment: What is your parent array , I cant seem to understand your question